# How to flatten and reduce XML using XSLT and best practice?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Apologies if this is a stupid question - I'm brand new to XSL as of today and I'm still trying to get used to the core concepts.

I have the following XML file with a hierarchical structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<EXCHANGE>
 <SCE>
  <SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_SCJC.SCE.SRS>1234567/1</SCE_SCJC.SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_SEQ2.SCE.SRS>01</SCE_SEQ2.SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_STUC.SCE.SRS>1234567</SCE_STUC.SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_AYRC.SCE.SRS>2022/23</SCE_AYRC.SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_CRSC.SCE.SRS>CRS123456</SCE_CRSC.SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_BLOK.SCE.SRS>01</SCE_BLOK.SCE.SRS>
   <SCE_DPTC.SCE.SRS>ABCD</SCE_DPTC.SCE.SRS>
   <STU>
    <STU.SRS>
     <STU_CODE.STU.SRS>22100814</STU_CODE.STU.SRS>
     <STU_NAME.STU.SRS>Test Student Name</STU_NAME.STU.SRS>
     <STU_DOB.STU.SRS>01011993</STU_DOB.STU.SRS>
     <STU_INEM.STU.SRS/>
    </STU.SRS>
   </STU>
   <DPT>
    <DPT.SRS>
     <DPT_CODE.DPT.SRS>ABCD</DPT_CODE.DPT.SRS>
     <DPT_NAME.DPT.SRS>Department Name</DPT_NAME.DPT.SRS>
    </DPT.SRS>
   </DPT>
   <CRS>
    <CRS.SRS>
     <CRS_CODE.CRS.SRS>CRS123456</CRS_CODE.CRS.SRS>
     <CRS_NAME.CRS.SRS>Course Name</CRS_NAME.CRS.SRS>
     <CRS_MOAC.CRS.SRS>FT</CRS_MOAC.CRS.SRS>
    </CRS.SRS>
   </CRS>
  </SCE.SRS>
 </SCE>
</EXCHANGE>
```

I need to do the following:

1. Flatten the structure
2. Take only specific elements
3. Rename the chosen elements

This is so that I can pass the resultant output into an API.

The output needs to look something like this:

```
<StudentRecord>
     <STUDENT_NO>1234567</STUDENT_NO>
     <STUDENT_NAME>Test Student Name</STUDENT_NAME>
     <DATE_OF_BIRTH>01011993</DATE_OF_BIRTH>
     <EMAIL_ADDRESS/>
     <FACULTY>ABCD</FACULTY>
     <DEGREE_NAME>Course Name</DEGREE_NAME>
</StudentRecord>
```

I've created the following XSL file (it has to be using XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/EXCHANGE/SCE/SCE.SRS">
        <xsl:element name="STUDENT_NO">
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE_SCJC.SCE.SRS"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="STUDENT_NAME">
            <xsl:value-of select="STU/STU.SRS/STU_NAME.STU.SRS"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="DATE_OF_BIRTH">
            <xsl:value-of select="STU/STU.SRS/STU_DOB.STU.SRS"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="EMAIL_ADDRESS">
            <xsl:value-of select="STU/STU.SRS/STU_INEM.STU.SRS"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="FACULTY">
            <xsl:value-of select="DPT/DPT.SRS/DPT_NAME.DPT.SRS"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="DEGREE_NAME">
            <xsl:value-of select="CRS/CRS.SRS/CRS_NAME.CRS.SRS"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs something very close to what I need, as I get the following output when I apply the XSL transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
  <STUDENT_NO>1234567/1</STUDENT_NO>
<STUDENT_NAME>Test Student Name</STUDENT_NAME>
<DATE_OF_BIRTH>01011993</DATE_OF_BIRTH>
<EMAIL_ADDRESS></EMAIL_ADDRESS>
<FACULTY>ABCD</FACULTY>
<DEGREE_NAME>Course Name</DEGREE_NAME>
```

Technically I could use this and pass it across to the API as is.  I feel however like this is not the best way to get what I'm after, and that there is a better way to pick certain elements from each node and change the element names.

Would what I've got be considered correct useage?  Is there a better way to get the specific elements I need into the required format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways this could be done. Here's how I would do it.
Having the different sections separated in individual templates would make it easy to add or remove elements later on if required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Create new root element -->
    <StudentRecord>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="EXCHANGE/SCE/SCE.SRS"/>
    </StudentRecord>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- General information -->
  <xsl:template match="SCE.SRS">
    <STUDENT_NO>
      <xsl:value-of select="SCE_STUC.SCE.SRS"/>
    </STUDENT_NO>
    <!-- Student information -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="STU/STU.SRS"/>
    <!-- Department information -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DPT/DPT.SRS"/>
    <!-- Course information -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CRS/CRS.SRS"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Student information -->
  <xsl:template match="STU.SRS">
    <STUDENT_NAME>
      <xsl:value-of select="STU_NAME.STU.SRS"/>
    </STUDENT_NAME>
    <DATE_OF_BIRTH>
      <xsl:value-of select="STU_DOB.STU.SRS"/>
    </DATE_OF_BIRTH>
    <EMAIL_ADDRESS>
      <xsl:value-of select="STU_INEM.STU.SRS"/>
    </EMAIL_ADDRESS>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Department information -->
  <xsl:template match="DPT.SRS">
    <FACULTY>
      <xsl:value-of select="DPT_NAME.DPT.SRS"/>
    </FACULTY>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Course information -->
  <xsl:template match="CRS.SRS">
    <DEGREE_NAME>
      <xsl:value-of select="CRS_NAME.CRS.SRS"/>  
    </DEGREE_NAME>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyho8J

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/EXCHANGE"> 
    <StudentRecord>
        <STUDENT_NO>
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE/SCE.SRS/SCE_SCJC.SCE.SRS" />
        </STUDENT_NO>
        <STUDENT_NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE/SCE.SRS/STU/STU.SRS/STU_NAME.STU.SRS" />
        </STUDENT_NAME>
        <DATE_OF_BIRTH>
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE/SCE.SRS/STU/STU.SRS/STU_DOB.STU.SRS" />
        </DATE_OF_BIRTH>
        <EMAIL_ADDRESS>
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE/SCE.SRS/STU/STU.SRS/STU_INEM.STU.SRS" />
        </EMAIL_ADDRESS>
        <FACULTY>
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE/SCE.SRS/DPT/DPT.SRS/DPT_CODE.DPT.SRS" />
        </FACULTY>
        <DEGREE_NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="SCE/SCE.SRS/CRS/CRS.SRS/CRS_NAME.CRS.SRS" />
        </DEGREE_NAME>
    </StudentRecord>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or maybe little more efficiently:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/EXCHANGE"> 
    <xsl:variable name="sce.srs" select="SCE/SCE.SRS" />
    <xsl:variable name="stu.srs" select="$sce.srs/STU/STU.SRS" />
    <xsl:variable name="dpt.srs" select="$sce.srs/DPT/DPT.SRS" />
    <xsl:variable name="crs.srs" select="$sce.srs/CRS/CRS.SRS" />
    <StudentRecord>
        <STUDENT_NO>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sce.srs/SCE_SCJC.SCE.SRS" />
        </STUDENT_NO>
        <STUDENT_NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="$stu.srs/STU_NAME.STU.SRS" />
        </STUDENT_NAME>
        <DATE_OF_BIRTH>
            <xsl:value-of select="$stu.srs/STU_DOB.STU.SRS" />
        </DATE_OF_BIRTH>
        <EMAIL_ADDRESS>
            <xsl:value-of select="$stu.srs/STU_INEM.STU.SRS" />
        </EMAIL_ADDRESS>
        <FACULTY>
            <xsl:value-of select="$dpt.srs/DPT_CODE.DPT.SRS" />
        </FACULTY>
        <DEGREE_NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="$crs.srs/CRS_NAME.CRS.SRS" />
        </DEGREE_NAME>
    </StudentRecord>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(The last two variables are not really necessary, since they are only used once. Their only purpose is to make the code more readable.)